# Rsync delete argument is not removing

Tags: bash, rsync

I am rsyncing directories 
`rsync --delete /home/pi/folder1/*.png /home/pi2/folder2/`
When i run the above command I am getting  `rsync: --delete does not work without --recursive (-r) or --dirs (-d).`
When I add `-r` rsync does not delete.
However if I `rsync --delete /home/pi/folder1/ /home/pi2/folder2/` deletion works.  But I can't use rsync like that because there is other data in the folder2 that I need to keep.

Comment: Maybe rsync has got problem comparing \*.png with ... folder/, I would very carefully try this: rsync --delete /home/pi/folder1/*.png /home/pi2/folder2/*.png . By carefully I mean to have a backup once you play around with delete commands not to loose any important data :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only delete extraneous files if you transfer a directory, but you can use `--exclude` to exclude all other files which are then also excluded from the deletion, e.g.

```
rsync -av --delete --include='*.png' --exclude='*' /home/pi/folder1/ /home/pi2/folder2
```

This would sync all `*.png` files from `folder1` (but not from subfolders) to `folder2` 
and delete extraneous `*.png` files in `folder2` (but not from subfolders of `folder2`).

Options:

- `-a` shortcut for `-rlptgoD`
- `-v` increase verbosity

As always: Test this using a test destination directory before running this on your data.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  I was coming back to answer the question but thanks.